# Merge two data frame on one exact match and one partial URL match

Tags: r

I have been trying to do a little tedious merge (**ON very large data**), on one exact match and one partial. I have tried couple ways (using pmatch, str_detect, grep with sapply) and got somewhat close results but trying to find an elegant solution. Any help insight will be greatly appreciated.

Another longer rout I found is to do a regular merge on common field (seesionId) and then write a for loop like below:

```
for( i in 1:nrow(my.test.daa) ){
my.test.daa$Part_match [i] = pmatch(my.test.daa$Link_URL[i], my.test.daa$Referer[i])
...get index i to also get the other columns from dataset frame
}
```

**New data - with duplicates**

```
pattern <- data.frame(SessionId = I(c("5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef1",
                                  "5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef2",
                                  "5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef3",
                                  "5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef4",
                                  "5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef5",
                                  "5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef1")), 
                  URL = I(c("somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288511/",
                            "somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288512/",
                            "somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288513/",
                            "somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288514/",
                            "somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288511/",
                            "somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288512/"
                  )))


dataset <- data.frame(SessionId = I(c("5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef1",
                                  "5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef3",
                                  "5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef5",
                                  "5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef7",
                                  "5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef1"
                     )), 
                  Referer = I(c("somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288511/110302288512/",
                                "somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288513/1103022815/",
                                "somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288513/11030228/",
                                "somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288465464/",
                                "somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288512/46545465/"
                  )))
```

**OLD** - Below is the sample code for the data.frams:

```
pattern <- data.frame(SessionId = I(c("5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef1",
                                  "5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef2",
                                  "5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef3",
                                  "5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef4",
                                  "5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef5",
                                  "5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef6")), 
                  URL = I(c("somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288511/",
                          "somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288512/",
                          "somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288513/",
                          "somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288514/",
                          "somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288511/",
                          "somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288512/"
                  )))


dataset <- data.frame(SessionId = I(c("5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef1",
                                "5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef3",
                                "5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef5",
                                "5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef7",
                                "5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef2"
                              )), 
              Referer = I(c("somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288511/110302288512/",
                          "somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288513/1103022815/",
                          "somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288513/11030228/",
                          "somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288465464/",
                          "somewebsite.com/abc/detail/1103022846546/"
                  )))
```

**NEW OUTPUT - WITH DUPLICATES**

```
    SessionId                           URL                                     Referer
5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef1  somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288511/    somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288511/110302288512/   
5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef3  somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288513/    somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288513/1103022815/
5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef1  somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288512/    somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288512/46545465/
```

So the **OLD** output would need to look like this:

```
    SessionId                           URL                                     Referer
5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef1  somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288511/    somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288511/110302288512/   
5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef3  somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288513/    somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288513/1103022815/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your data in the long format and then process by ID within a `data.table`   .

```
library(reshape2)
dat <- do.call(rbind,lapply(list(pattern,dataset),function(x)
                             melt(x,id.vars='SessionId')))
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(dat,key='SessionId')

DT[,if(.N ==2)
       if(length(grep(value[1],value[2]))>0) as.list(value)
   ,by='SessionId']

                    SessionId                                       V1                                                    V2
1: 5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef1 somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288511/ somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288511/110302288512/
2: 5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef3 somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288513/   somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288513/1103022815/
```

**EDIT** benchmarking the 2 solutions with the OP data ( lazy to create a big sample dataset).  **eddi solution is 3 times faster**. The result is expected, my solution is slower since it uses an extra step of reshaping data with `reshape2`( a little bit slow).

```
microbenchmark(eddi(),agstudy(),times=100)
Unit: milliseconds
      expr      min        lq    median        uq        max neval
    eddi() 3.232808  3.427557  3.553092  3.768891   8.665698   100
 agstudy() 9.998795 10.615281 11.208633 12.438759 129.517833   100
```

Here the code used for benchmarking:

```
library(inline)
library(Rcpp)
library(reshape2)

eddi <- function(){
  library(data.table)
  pattern = data.table(pattern, key = 'SessionId')
  dataset = data.table(dataset, key = 'SessionId')
  dataset[pattern, nomatch = 0][string_compare(URL, Referer) == 1]
}

agstudy <- function(){
  dat <- do.call(rbind,lapply(list(pattern,dataset),function(x)
    melt(x,id.vars='SessionId')))
  library(data.table)
  DT <- data.table(dat,key='SessionId')

  DT[,if(.N ==2)
    if(length(grep(value[1],value[2]))>0) as.list(value)
     ,by='SessionId']

}

library('microbenchmark')
microbenchmark(eddi(),agstudy(),times=100)
```

**EDIT2** to mangae duplicated cases, it is better to to use the wide format. Inspired from @eddit function , Here my version without creating the Rcpp function.

```
  pattern = data.table(pattern, key = 'SessionId')
  dataset = data.table(dataset, key = 'SessionId')
  dataset[pattern, nomatch = 0][mapply(grep,URL,Referer)==1]
```

PS I benchmark this one with eddi function, and the latter still slightly faster

```
microbenchmark(eddi(),agstudy(),times=100)
Unit: milliseconds
      expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
    eddi() 3.684126 3.819901 4.007634 4.395048 8.490101   100
 agstudy() 4.057697 4.250171 4.595298 4.835747 8.581503   100
```

Comment: you should replace `dd$Referer` in your grep with `x['Referer']`, that's why you got different results; unfortunately I don't see how this improves on OP - you just replaced the for loop with an apply loop

Comment: @eddi I completely modify may answer now.

Comment: I'm curious to see benchmarks of this vs Rcpp (I can't do them right now)

Comment: +1, thanks for the bench - I think big data bench is going to be more illuminating, and maybe since OP has that, they can do it :)

Comment: @agstudy Thanks for tiny elegant solution and for benchmarking solutions as well. Your code piece runs fine on the test data I provided but I think it won't return correct results if there are duplicates. In fact there are duplicates in the actual data. I have updated data in my post...

Comment: @DevPatel my code don't handle duplicated case. But I create a new function. You can see my last edit.

Comment: @agstudy - Awesome, I think (??) that should do it. Actually I was thinking to try the similar function using `grepl` and `agrep` using `sapply`, but didn't realize about `mapply`. 

I really wanted to try eddi's solution, but I am getting compilation error related C++ when I try to run `cxxfunction`. Till then, I only have your solution as last resort..lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the required string vector comparison function exists in R, but you can just write yours. Note that there are various checks one should do in the code below, especially if one wants to use the `string_compare` function outside of this problem, that I don't (e.g. check if the two vectors have same length):

```
library(inline)
library(Rcpp)

string_compare = cxxfunction(signature(x = 'character', y = 'character'), '
  CharacterVector a(x), b(y);
  NumericVector res(a.size(), 1.0);

  for (int i = 0, size = a.size(); i < size; ++i) {
    int alen = a[i].size();
    int blen = b[i].size();
    if (alen > blen) {
      res[i] = 0;
      continue;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < alen; ++j) {
      if (a[i][j] != b[i][j]) {
        res[i] = 0;
        break;
      }
    }    
  }

  return res;
', plugin = 'Rcpp')

library(data.table)
pattern = data.table(pattern, key = 'SessionId')
dataset = data.table(dataset, key = 'SessionId')

dataset[pattern, nomatch = 0][string_compare(URL, Referer) == 1]
#                    SessionId                                               Referer                                      URL
#1: 5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef1 somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288511/110302288512/ somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288511/
#2: 5b8cc8794a02ba868db21faef3   somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288513/1103022815/ somewebsite.com/abc/detail/110302288513/
```

Comment: @eddi - Thanks for quick respond. Actually I am trying to run your solution but some reason, I get below errors even if just try to run your function "string_compare":


    `Error in signature(x = "character", y = "character") : 
  unused argument (y = "character")`

Comment: @DevPatel and you didn't get any errors loading `inline` or `Rcpp`? If you're copy-pasting the above code, I don't know why you'd get that error, sorry.

Comment: @eddi - Yes I did load `inline` and `Rcpp`. I know its weird and I am sure your code would be working fine since agstudy was able to do the bench. Even I can't run the examples from `cxxfunction` help page. So, it must be my 64 bit R or something of that sort :(. 

a quick question though - can your code handle the duplicate data as well? I have updated new data frame with duplicate scenario.

Comment: @DevPatel yep, it produces the output you want in the duplicate scenario (the only difference is the output is sorted by `SessionId`)

Comment: @DevPatel maybe you get better result using this [version of string_compare](https://gist.github.com/agstudy/f7ed353e047450d38b6c).

Comment: @agstudy thanks again for sharing this. I am still not able to run c++ code on any of my machines(I tried on 3 computers lol).

Comment: @DevPatel you might want to open a separate question about that :)